Jacobson radical of an infinite product of modules
For an $R$-module $M$, the Jacobson radical of $M$ (denoted $J(M)$) is defined to be the intersection of all maximal $R$-submodules of $M$. Given an $R$-linear map $f:M\to N$ between two $R$-modules, it holds that $f(J(M))\subseteq J(N)$. Given an arbitrary family of $R$-modules $(M_i)_{i\in I}$, we obtain $J(\prod_{i\in I} M_i)\subseteq \prod_{i\in I}J(M_i)$ by considering the projections $\prod_{i\in I} M_i \to M_i$, and $\bigoplus_{i\in I}J(M_i)\subseteq J(\prod_{i\in I} M_i)$ by considering the inclusions $M_i \to \prod_{i\in I} M_i$. It follows that $\bigoplus_{i\in I}J(M_i)=J(\bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i)$, but it is unclear whether $\prod_{i\in I}J(M_i)=J(\prod_{i\in I}M_i)$. The analogous identity for Jacobson radical of rings holds but the argument doesn't apply here. Can you prove the identity, or in case it fails, give a counterexample?

Why $f(J(M))\subseteq J(N)$? This is only clear to me when $f$ is an epimorphism. There will be counterexamples when $f$ is injective. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326867/frattini-subgroup-is-normal-monotone for the non-abelian counterexample (the frattini subgroup is for groups what the radical is for modules).

$f(J(M))\subseteq J(N)$ is equivalent to $J(M)\subseteq f^{-1}(J(N))$, and it suffices to show that for every maximal submodule $S$ of $N$, $f^{-1}(S)$ is either maximal or $=M$. This is because $M/f^{-1}(S)$ injects into $N/S$ (a simple $R$-module), and the image is either everything or 0, corresponding to the two cases. This relies on the $R$-module structures on $M/f^{-1}(S)$ and $N/S$, which you don't have in then nonabelian setting, but I intend to restrict to modules over a ring $R$.

Thanks! That works indeed.

If $R$ is commutative, then $J(M) = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{m} \subseteq R \text{ maximal}} \mathfrak{m} M$, see The (Jacobson) radical of modules over commutative rings. Hence, if $R$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, then $J(M) = \mathfrak{m} M$. In this setting, your question becomes: Is the inclusion $\mathfrak{m} \prod_{i \in I} M_i \subseteq \prod_{i \in I} \mathfrak{m} M_i$ an equality? It is when $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated. Conversely, when it holds for all families of modules, $\mathfrak{m}$ must be finitely generated: Choose an indexing $\mathfrak{m} = \{m_i : i \in I\}$ (you could have $I := \mathfrak{m}$ and $m_i := i$, but the notation is simpler with indices), and let $M_i := R$. Then $(m_i)_{i \in I} \in \mathfrak{m}^I = \mathfrak{m} R^I$. So we have a finite linear combination in $R^I$ with coefficients in $\mathfrak{m}$, and hence get a finite subset $T \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ such that each $m_i$ is a linear combination with coefficients in $T$, which means $\mathfrak{m} = \langle T \rangle$.
So for a counterexample any commutative local ring with a maximal that is not finitely generated will do, for example the localization of $k[x_0,x_1,\dotsc]$ at the prime $\langle x_0,x_1,\dotsc \rangle$.

Thank you! I didn't know about the formula over commutative rings. Now I'm wondering if the lower bound $\bigoplus_{i\in I}J(M_i)$ can be achieved ... (when $I$ is infinite and all $J(M_i)\ne0$).

Would be a good follow-up question. For direct sums it then of course holds in the commutative case.
